# Solving Ordinary Differential Equation involving trig functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the differential equation:

```
Dy/dx(tanx) + 2y = x(cosecx)
```

Where y = 0 when x = π/2

I don't know where to start with this, and haven't done many questions like this before. Help anyone?

Comment: There is a standard technique for solving first-order linear o.d.e.s like this one: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*:

$y(x) = u(x)v(x)$ then 
$y'(x) = u'v + v'u $

Comment: Shouldn't it be $..+..$

Comment: @ArchisWelankar my bad sorry